# Error loading a model in runtime generated by Weka Explorer

Tags: java, weka

I am using Weka Explorer 3.8.1 to generate an ML model and use it in my java runtime code (Using the maven library nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable v3.8.1). But, whenever I save the classification model (right clicking the result in the Results List in the Classify tab) and load the model from my code by:

```
 Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath+"tree.model");
```

The line above raises an StreamCorruptedException with the message: "invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF".

I would appreciate any ideas for the reason of this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: After three days I found the solution. Initially, I placed my model file in the WEB-INF folder on my web server and when I moved it to the src/main/resources folder it solved the issue.